# Is this the faster way to test cpu load using shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, health-monitoring

I'm relatively new to shell scripting and I'm in the process of writing my own health checking scripts using bash.

Is the following script to test cpu load the best I can have in terms of performance, readability and maintainability?

```
#!/bin/sh

getloadavg5 () {
  echo $(cat /proc/loadavg | cut -f2 -d' ')
}

getnumcpus () {
  echo $(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep '^processor' | wc -l)
}

awk \
  -v failthold=0.8 \
  -v warnthold=0.7 \
  -v loadavg=$(getloadavg5) \
  -v numcpus=$(getnumcpus) \
  'BEGIN {
    ratio=loadavg/numcpus
    if (ratio >= failthold) exit 2
    if (ratio >= warnthold) exit 1
    exit 0
  }'
```

Comment: Re: the best in terms of performance, readability and maintainability — i would say no.

Comment: can you tell me more, please?

Comment: It's not clear what you are actually trying to do; the values that are pulled from the command shown in your question are barely a glimpse of what the machine is doing at any given moment. The second command is merely informational and isn't actively changing.

Comment: This script is meant to be run by a Consul agent. It's not the only one. I'd like to know if there's a better way to do this particular check. Thanks

Comment: I would recommend using a real utility to see what is taking place; `top`, `htop`, etc. are all going to provide much better information.

Comment: Why? I need to do it programmatically

Comment: Basically your script isn't going to provide any more useful information than the `uptime` command. It's one command/word, so I'm not understanding why you need a script at all.

Comment: agree with comments above, but want to add that `echo $(cmd_producing_output)` is inefficient use of resources. For both of your functions you can just use the basic code inside of `$()` , ie `cat /proc/loadavg | cut -f2 -d' '` and get the same result. Actually, it worth testing to see if  you can avoid the `cat` process as well, with just `cut -f2 -d' ' < /proc/loadavg` . Good luck.

Comment: Just came here to remind that load-average is not *in any way* a measure of just the CPU load.

Answer (score 2):

This might be more suitable for the [code review stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but without condoning the use of load averages in this way, here are some ideas:

```
#!/bin/sh
read -r one five fifteen rest < /proc/loadavg
cpus=$(grep -c '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo)

awk \
  -v failthold=0.8 \
  -v warnthold=0.7 \
  -v loadavg="$five" \
  -v numcpus="$cpus" \
  'BEGIN {
    ratio=loadavg/numcpus
    if (ratio >= failthold) exit 2
    if (ratio >= warnthold) exit 1
    exit 0
  }'
```

It doesn't have any of the unnecessary cats/echos.

It also happens to run faster thanks to forking 1 or 2 times (depending on shell) instead of ~10, but if performance is an issue then shell scripts should be avoided in general.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's what I was looking for. Which technology would you use to implement a series of health checks that run at intervals on any VM of your infrastructure?